# PHP Query won't work with DELETE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have connection, and I wan't delete one record by choosing ID (option have value of row ID in db)

```
<form class="form">
      <?php
      require "connect.php";
      $select = $_POST['del_zaint'];
      if(isset($_POST['Del'])){
        $$que = "DELETE FROM `zainteresowania` WHERE `zainteresowania`.`id` = '".$select."'";
        mysqli_query($db, $que);
      }
      mysqli_close($db);
      ?>

      <span class="main-page__info">Usuń rekord zainteresowań.</span>
      <select name="del_zaint">
        <option disabled selected>Wybierz rekord do usunięcia</option>
        <?php
        require "connect.php";
        $que = "SELECT * from zainteresowania";
        $wynik = mysqli_query($db, $que);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik)){
          echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">"."[".$row['id']."] ".$row['zainteresowanie']."</option>";
        }
        mysqli_close($db);
        ?>
      </select>
      <input name="Del" type="submit" value="Usuń">
    </form>
```

Nothing is done by this :/ I choose option and after clicking submit with name = Del, it won't work, just reset to normal position. (Adding informations to db and showing from it works well)

Comment: Can you show us your html form? And do you get any error?

Comment: What this contains `$_POST['del_zaint'];`?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I already gave full form

Comment: Is is the exact code? because you have not set `method="post"` with your form tag.

Comment: Maybe MySQL user doesn't have delete permission

Comment: Now I'm late - but obvious error is `$$que`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

You miss the method in the form tag.
Also, I Change the SQL query

```
$que = "DELETE FROM `zainteresowania` WHERE id = '".$select."'";
```

Below code is working on my system. You have to use the `SQL injection` for secure

```
$db->real_escape_string($_POST['del_zaint'])
```

> instated of delete the record, Make a column like status in the database and change the status 0 or 1.

You can refer the site for deleting the record

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp

```
 <?php
include('db/connection.php');
      if(isset($_POST['Del'])){

        echo $select = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['del_zaint']);
        $que = "DELETE FROM `zainteresowania` WHERE id = '".$select."'";
            if (mysqli_query($db, $que)) {
                  echo "Record deleted successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($db);
            }
      mysqli_close($db);
  }
      ?>

<form class="form" method="POST" action="#">
      <span class="main-page__info">Usuń rekord zainteresowań.</span>

      <select name="del_zaint">
        <option disabled selected>Wybierz rekord do usunięcia</option>
        <?php
        $que = "SELECT * from zainteresowania";
        $wynik = mysqli_query($db, $que);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik)){
          echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">"."[".$row['id']."] ".$row['zainteresowanie']."</option>";
        }
        mysqli_close($db);
        ?>
      </select>
      <input name="Del" type="submit" value="Usuń">
    </form>
```

Comment: @TheTanadu, Glad to help you. Give me upvote and accept the answer so that next time any user can easily check the correct answer

Comment: I gave you upvote, but I don't have 15 reputations so no one will see it :/

Answer (score 0):

Please change this to:

```
require "connect.php";
$select = $_POST['del_zaint'];
if(isset($_POST['Del'])){
  $que = "DELETE FROM `zainteresowania` WHERE `zainteresowania`.`id` = $select";
  mysqli_query($db, $que);
}
mysqli_close($db);
```

I have had cases where PHP only notices variables if they are included directly in double quotes and but not single quotes. The other option is to use string concatenation so that PHP knows where the variable is.

```
require "connect.php";
    $select = $_POST['del_zaint'];
    if(isset($_POST['Del'])){
      $que = "DELETE FROM `zainteresowania` WHERE `zainteresowania`.`id` = '".$select."'";
      mysqli_query($db, $que);
    }
    mysqli_close($db);
```

Comment: You might want to provide some information to OP what exactly it is you changed in his code.

Comment: Thanks @Jerodev, i have added an explanation o my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is you have not set `method="post"` with your form tag. So set it there and give it a try.

A suggestion:

Chage your query like this:

```
$que = "DELETE FROM `zainteresowania` WHERE `zainteresowania`.`id` = '".$select."'";  // Check the changes I made around $select.
```

Comment: That should do exactly the same as the posted query, as in double qoutes, variables are replaced

Comment: Won't work too > I will add full form in main post to give more place to work with.

Comment: that was my first comment under your question:  
What this contains `$_POST['del_zaint'];`

Comment: you have not set `method="post"` with your form tag.

Comment: Damn god... thank you! Early morning and I don't saw that... :D maan - now I'm so much angry on myself I took your time... :D

Comment: I see SQL injection in the making, please use PDO and make the web a safer place

Comment: i know i know - it's just for practice in university, it will not be in web PDO only in normal projects

Comment: @TheTanadu, I am updating my answer as per my comment. Would you please accept it?